# Cursor is invisible until I start typing

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I have selected a text object and use the text tool, the insertion point is not having a visible cursor.

[image: lorem ipsum]

When I type a letter, I see one cursor blink and then the cursor turns invisible again.

[image]

After one blink, the cursor is not visible any longer.

[image]

Is there an idea behind not being able to see the cursor?

How do I have the cursor always visible?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't reproduce this problem. Perhaps it's a bug? Check with Adobe. Tech support is off topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: I did not suspect this to be a bug, but more something that every illustrator user gets used to sooner or later. I do not see it a tech support question but in the community category.

Comment: It's a tech issue. It's not normal behavior. It *could* be due to a bad/corrupt active font. Often anything odd with the cursor in AI is due to font issues - especially cursors blinking when they shouldn't or cursors not appearing.

Comment: The fact that it is not a normal behavior is something I accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not happen, but also not sure its an AI problem. Might be some conflict in your OS UI, desktop color theme, accessibility settings overriding AI settings, things like that. I can sure see the cursor in my AI CC.

Something you can try is to restore default preferences:

- Press and hold Alt+Control+Shift (Windows) or Option+Command+Shift (macOS) as you start Illustrator. The new preferences files are created the next time you start Illustrator.

Also, see if any of these options do anything.

[image]

Comment: Unchecking did not do anything, but I accept the answer!

Comment: Oh wait, when I had restarted AI, I got a cursor that I can see all the time, but only after trying some times. I do not always get it. Seems there is some mode I have to enter in the text labels. That mode is enabled when I start editing the text which was not the case before.